# Django channels redis channel layer opens a lot of connections

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-asyncio, django-channels

We ported a part of our application to django channels recently, using the redis channel layer backend. A part of our setup still runs on python2 in a docker which is why we use redis pub/sub to send messages back to the client. A global listener ([inspired by this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/Ny7otqAgqrQ)) catches all messages and distributes them into the django channels system. It all works fine so far but I see a lot of debug messages `Creating tcp connection...` passing by. The output posted below corresponds to one event. Both the listener as well as the consumer seem to be creating two redis connections. I have not enough knowledge about the underlying mechanism to be able to tell if this the expected behavior, thus me asking here. Is this to be expected?

The Listener uses a global channel layer instance:

```
# maps the publish type to a method name of the django channel consumer
PUBLISH_TYPE_EVENT_MAP = {
    'state_change': 'update_client_state',
    'message': 'notify_client',
}
channel_layer = layers.get_channel_layer()


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = u'Opens a connection to Redis and listens for messages, ' \
           u'and then whenever it gets one, sends the message onto a channel ' \
           u'in the Django channel system'

    ...

    def broadcast_message(self, msg_body):
        group_name = msg_body['subgrid_id'].replace(':', '_')
        try:
            event_name = PUBLISH_TYPE_EVENT_MAP[msg_body['publish_type']]
        # backwards compatibility
        except KeyError:
            event_name = PUBLISH_TYPE_EVENT_MAP[msg_body['type']]

        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
            group_name, {
                "type": event_name,
                "kwargs": msg_body.get('kwargs'),
            })
```

The consumer is a `JsonWebsocketConsumer` that is initialized like this

```
class SimulationConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):
        """
        Establishes the connection with the websocket.
        """
        logger.debug('Incoming connection...')
        # subgrid_id can be set dynamically, see property subgrid_id
        self._subgrid_id = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['subgrid_id']
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        self.accept()
```

And the method that is called from the listener:

````
def update_client_state(self, event):
    """
    Public facing method that pushes the state of a simulation back
    to the client(s). Has to be called through django channels
    ```async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)...``` method
    """
    logger.debug('update_client_state event %s', event)
    current_state = self.redis_controller.fetch_state()
    data = {'sim_state': {
        'sender_sessid': self.session_id,
        'state_data': current_state}
    }
    self.send_json(content=data)
````

A single event gives me this output

```
listener_1              | DEBUG !! data    {'publish_type': 'state_change', 'subgrid_id': 'subgrid:6d1624b07e1346d5907bbd72869c00e8'}
listener_1              | DEBUG !! event_name    update_client_state
listener_1              | DEBUG !! kwargs    None
listener_1              | DEBUG !! group_name    subgrid_6d1624b07e1346d5907bbd72869c00e8
listener_1              | DEBUG Using selector: EpollSelector
listener_1              | DEBUG Parsing Redis URI 'redis://:@redis-threedi-server:6379/13'
listener_1              | DEBUG Creating tcp connection to ('redis-threedi-server', 6379)
listener_1              | DEBUG Parsing Redis URI 'redis://:@redis-threedi-server:6379/13'
listener_1              | DEBUG Creating tcp connection to ('redis-threedi-server', 6379)
threedi-server_1        | DEBUG Parsing Redis URI 'redis://:@redis-threedi-server:6379/13'
threedi-server_1        | DEBUG Creating tcp connection to ('redis-threedi-server', 6379)
threedi-server_1        | DEBUG update_client_state event {'type': 'update_client_state', 'kwargs': None}
threedi-server_1        | DEBUG Parsing Redis URI 'redis://:@redis-threedi-server:6379/13'
threedi-server_1        | DEBUG Creating tcp connection to ('redis-threedi-server', 6379)
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you maybe find the solution?

Comment: Not s solution, but a similar issue when using `djangochannelsrestframework`: https://github.com/hishnash/djangochannelsrestframework/issues/13 Linking to that here, in case someone has a hint...